# Circuit Breaker Size For Main Panel

Tags: electrical, basement, subpanel

I'm planning on adding a sub panel to my basement. I purchased a Square D 100 amp panel. Is there any code requirement for the size of breaker I need in the Main?  My neighbor used 50amp. I've seen you tubers say 90 or 100amp. I will have a 1.5 ton heat pump and a bunch of outlets and lights throughout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum size of the feed breaker needs to be less than or equal to the sub-panel main breaker. One reason to use a 90 is that it permits using less expensive 2AWG aluminum for the feeder wires, if the loads you are running from the sub-panel don't amount to more than 90A service required there. Unless it's a very short run (a couple feet from the main panel) copper is an extra expense for no benefit. *Even if it's a very short run that's true, but the amount of money is not huge in that case.*

You need to do a **load calculation** to determine how much load your present service can actually support on top of the loads you already have. If your service is not large enough for the additional loads you may need to increase it.

You also need to do a **load calculation** for the loads you plan to run from the sub-panel. That sets the minimum size of the breaker and wiring to feed it. Between the minimum and maximum you can pick a size that you like.